# 500 Second Command Timeout - Too long?

Tags: c#, sql-server

We're having an issue with an important app in production. As a short-term fix, we're increasing the command timeout in many places throughout the code:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(szSQL, conn) {CommandTimeout = _cmdTimeout};
```

The developer is using an initial default of 500 seconds (8+ minutes). Until we get a long-term fix in place, this is our solution. My concern is the number of seconds to use. 8+ minutes seems like a long time (too long), and I'm wondering what other problems could be introduced by using that amount of time. Would it be better to try and stay under 3-4 minutes? Or is 8 just fine?

Comment: I'm afraid to ask what might take 3-4 minutes...

Comment: I think your 'other problems' will be an angry mob of employees/customers

Comment: Well, I guess it depends. How many of your users do you think will be willing to wait 8+ minutes to get a result? I think you should focus on optimizing the query than worrying about how long your timeout should be.

Comment: You could easily run out of worker threads to process new queries if all the workers are tied up executing 8 minute queries.

Comment: Hey, I'm with you guys. I've inherited this and we're about to start a huge refactoring effort to fix things like this. The process can take a day to run, so customers aren't at least sitting there waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Whatever you are running would probably run much faster on the server side as a stored procdure or a view.  That is a long time.  The most I would wait is 60 seconds.

Comment: IMO 30s is too high 3-4m will drain your connection pool if you are under any kind of load

Comment: Depends on what you are doing.  It is good to adopt an asynchronous model.  Have a thread spawn off taking charge of the `SqlCommand`, and let the end user know when it is done.

Comment: Along with that idea, only dedicate a limited amount of threads for the number of connections, and store "overflowing" jobs in a queue.

Comment: Does the job have to be repeated? if so how often? is it possible to run the query (as a psudo-report) store the output, when the user clicks the "button" just return the stored output, and refresh only as needed?

Comment: @Jay Issues like what you just mentioned will be part of making this thing "right" going forward. Appreciate the tip.

Comment: But 3, 4, or 8 minutes are just arbitrary time lengths. Whether this is 'too long' is unclear based on your question.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem in using 8 minutes as a timeout when necessary. AFAIK, SSMS has an infinite timeout when running queries!

I would suggest however a slightly different approach based on this extracted code:

```
private static bool IsRetryAfterException(SqlException aSqlExc)
{
  if (aSqlExc != null)
  {
    // If anybody finds a better way than this, please update!
    return aSqlExc.Message.Contains("The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding");
  }
  else
    throw new ArgumentNullException("The parameter 'aSqlExc' cannot be null.");
}

private int CallExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand aCmd)
{
  for (int iRetry = 1; iRetry <= m_MaxTimeoutRetry; iRetry++)
    try
    {
      return aCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException wSqlE)
    {
      if (iRetry == m_MaxTimeoutRetry || !IsRetryAfterException(wSqlE))
        throw;

      // otherwise, we double the timeout and retry
      aCmd.CommandTimeout = 2 * aCmd.CommandTimeout;
      // let SQL breathe a bit!
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(aCmd.CommandTimeout * 10);
    }

    // This code cannot be reached but the compiler thinks otherwise 
    // this is because it cannot know that m_MaxTimeoutRetry is always >= 1 for the for-loop
    throw new DataAccessException();
}
```

In our code, all the queries are called through the CallExecuteNonQuery method.
This could be difficult for you to change your code but you can use Lambda expression for that and easily modify your existing code so that it goes through that unique method with very little changes...

So the question is why using a loop and retrying? This is because of SQL dead locks. My experience is that it is best to let a command time out quickly say 30s and to retry if it timed out by doubling the timin out and letting SQL breathing than to let all the queries have a big time out by default.

I hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: +1 for the tip. We actually have a class (in a different department) called SqlDeadlockHelper that does retries. That will be part of our refactoring effort.